# Rewrite command handler

Tags: discord.js

I want to rewrite my command handler due to it breaking if I attempt to make a new command that's a little bit different, and somehow manages to break it. Someone can help by giving me a new code fully or just fixing mine. The error is somewhere in the: I don't know why, I think due to I didn't define config or name, but I would like some help with this please. Thank you!

```
      let pull = require(`../src/commands/${dirs}/${file}`);
      bot.commands.set(pull.config.name, pull);
      if (pull.config.aliases) pull.config.aliases.forEach(a => bot.aliases.set(a, pull.config.name));
    };
```

Heres the full code.

```
const logger = require("../utils/logger"); 
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require("fs")
const ms = require('ms');


module.exports = (bot) => {
  const load = dirs => {
    const commands = readdirSync(`./src/commands/${dirs}/`).filter(d => d.endsWith('.js')); 

    for (let file of commands) { //for each of these files
      let pull = require(`../src/commands/${dirs}/${file}`);
      bot.commands.set(pull.config.name, pull);
      if (pull.config.aliases) pull.config.aliases.forEach(a => bot.aliases.set(a, pull.config.name));
    };

  };
  readdir(`./src/commands/`, (err, directories) => {
    if (err) logger.error(err); 
    var dirArray = [];
    directories.forEach((f, i) => { 
      if (lstatSync(`./src/commands/${f}`)) {  
        dirArray.push(f);
      }
    });

    dirArray.forEach(x => load(x));
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at mine if you want:

https://github.com/azul-i/shuxue

works with subdirs, required argument lengths, aliases, and admin requirement.

If you go with this, you will need to check main.js, handlers/commands.js and events/message.js

lmk if you need help understanding any of it.